# updateSearchResultsForSearchController won't work with UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift2

I'm following [this tuto](http://ahmedabdurrahman.com/2015/08/31/how-to-switch-view-controllers-using-segmented-control-swift/).
But I would like to add a *Search Bar* just upon the **Live Photos & Info** Segmented Control, then redirect the searched words to the **Live Photos** or **Info** views.
I tried the *Search Bar and Search Display Controller* But fails because it needs a *Table View*.
Then I tried a *Search Bar* and tried to get the searched words by using this function:

```
//MARK: - UISearchBarDelegate
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController)
{
    print("Looking for \(searchController.searchBar.text!)")
}
```

But it still not works.
Somebody already had this problem?

EDIT for @rptwsthi and @katleta3000:
Here are my delegates: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating

And I set it like that:

```
@IBOutlet var searchBar: UISearchBar!
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  searchBar.delegate = self
}
```

UPDATE:
This works great:

```
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked( searchBar: UISearchBar)
{
        print("Looking at \(searchBar.text!)")

}
```

When I press **Return** *searchBarSearchButtonClicked* is executed but when I just type keys *updateSearchResultsForSearchController* is not executed, so I don't think it's due to delegate.

Comment: It is hard to tell from your question, but may be you have forgot to delegate search bar view your view controller.

Comment: The  tutorial link you provided seems to have nothing common with your code. Look at @rptwsthi comment, did you set your `delegate` manually or via Interface Builder?

Comment: @katleta3000 Thanks for your comment. I have updated my question with how I set the delegate.  
PS: The tuto is just to set the context :)

Comment: @VivienG another possible problem can be in your controller reference? How do you hold it? Maybe your view controller is released, so delegate methods won't be called. And of course check your `searchBar` in `viewDidLoad()` is it `nil` or not in setting delegate?

Comment: I added an update for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's appeared that `func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController)` is only for **TableView**.
For View only it's `func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String)`